# Run a cron job in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cron

I would like to write a cron job that has to run a PHP script at 6am, 11am,2pm,4pm on each day.

Can you please help me with this? I wrote a shell task in shells and I want to run that task at the timings i said in the earlier statement.

Thanks.

Comment: You already asked this here [cron tab not working php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008270/cron-tab-not-working-php)

Answer (score 2):

Link from CakePHP's book on this issue: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html

(older version of the docs): http://book.cakephp.org/view/1110/Running-Shells-as-cronjobs

Answer (score -2):

you can set cron job like this in cakephp.

0 */4 * * * wget http://domainname.come/index.php/controllers/action.

Comment: This should be avoided as the whole point of using a cron job is to avoid hanging a connection with the web server and also avoiding request timeout.