# cron tab not working php

Tags: php, cakephp, cron

I added a cronjob by entering this command - crontab -e. I added the following tasks in that file-

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/web/vendors/shells/aggregated_deals.php
*/5 * * * * /var/www/web/vendors/shells/deals.php
```

These are php scripts. after that i restarted the apache server,but these scripts are not executing. And syslog log file is empty.
please help me to run this cron.

Comment: Did you try to run it by yourself manualy in your browser ? Did you try to run in command line with php ?

Comment: is it cake1.3 oder 2.0? looks like 1.3 to me

Comment: then the documentation should help you: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1110/Running-Shells-as-cronjobs

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that will run by itself - you need to run the scripts using the PHP interpreter, like this:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/web/vendors/shells/aggregated_deals.php
```

Note that your installation may have `php` elsewhere - use the command `which php` on the command line to find out the location.

Comment: now i edited my crontab by adding /usr/bin/php but still those two files are not executed

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can execute a PHP file by calling it like that, I always use a curl:

```
*/5 * * * * curl http://domain.com/page
```

Or I guess you could run it using the `php` command itself if you don't want to use the web server:

```
*/5 * * * * php /var/www/web/vendors/shells/aggregated_deals.php
```

What ever you type after the stars in the crontab rule will be the command execute against the system. If you run the command "/var/www/web/vendors/shells/aggregated_deals.php" in terminal I bet nothing happens...you need to invoke this as a PHP script.

Comment: `curl` works, but you could run into script timeouts with such roundabout web invocation (CLI invocation doesn't have a time limit by default, IIRC)

Comment: @Piskvor: Good to know, thanks. I'm about to scurry off and change all of these on my servers to use the CLI :)

Comment: YW - That's what I did, after finding out that a housekeeping script called with `wget` was timing out at 60 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call php-cli with the right user ?

`*/5 * * * * www-data php /var/www/web/vendors/shells/aggregated_deals.php`

OR

`*/5 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/web/vendors/shells/aggregated_deals.php`

Or something like that.
Have you already installed php-cli ?

Comment: If xe's using `crontab -e` as a normal user, xe should be editing that user's per-user crontab file; it's not necessary to specify the user there.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that you have PHP CLI available. You can do it by running this:

```
$ php -v
```

If you see some sane output, then PHP CLI is available. Otherwise you'll need to install it. Installation depends on the distro you're using.

Second, if you want to run CLI scripts directly, you need to make them executable:

```
$ chmod +x /var/www/web/vendors/shells/aggregated_deals.php
$ chmod +x /var/www/web/vendors/shells/deals.php
```

Third, PHP CLI scripts are not related to apache and you don't need to restart it to make CLI scripts work.

Comment: all the above are fine here-.still the scripts are not running

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the server to execute the files with PHP. Do all the stesps as described in Elnurs answer, and put these as your lines in cron:

```
*/5 * * * * php -f /var/www/web/vendors/shells/aggregated_deals.php > /tmp/my.log 2>&1
*/5 * * * * php -f /var/www/web/vendors/shells/deals.php > /tmp/my.log 2>&1
```

If that doesn't work you may need to include the entire path to PHP.
I've also just added some lines to make the script log any output.

Comment: Thanks,now the cron is running but getting this error 'PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Shell' not found in /var/www/web/vendors/shells/deals.php on line 3'. is it related to linking issue?

Comment: In that case I have fixed your cron issue, you need to fix the PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it cake style... you must run

```
cake shellName shellParam
```

i your case it would be

```
cake aggregated_deals > /tmp/my.log
cake deals > /tmp/my.log 2>&1
```

this cake is in your cake folder, and you should be running it from your app folder... i am not sure how to do this from cron but that is what you have wrong...

This is asuming those scripts are valid cakeShells

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the server to execute the files with PHP. Do all the stesps as described in Elnurs answer, and put these as your lines in cron:

```
*/5 * * * * php -f /var/www/web/vendors/shells/aggregated_deals.php > /tmp/my.log 2>&1
*/5 * * * * php -f /var/www/web/vendors/shells/deals.php > /tmp/my.log 2>&1

$ chmod +x /var/www/web/vendors/shells/aggregated_deals.php
$ chmod +x /var/www/web/vendors/shells/deals.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is posting a long time after, but it looks like i'm not the only one.

Anyway my suggestion would be to add the path to the php in the cron line:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/web/vendors/shells/aggregated_deals.php > /tmp/my.log 2>&1
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/web/vendors/shells/deals.php > /tmp/my.log 2>&1
```

Again make sure the permissions are good