# How to set command for cron job cake php

Tags: cakephp, cron, cpanel

I am working in cake php Now I want to send weekly status mail to all register user for this i have get all user detal and weekly activity detail

and added mail function in user/test  usercontroller and test action Here I am getting all user and their weekly detail and after that sending mail.

When i hit this url it send mail in my inbox

I want how we can add this controller action in cron job cpanel ?

Currently I am giving full path in C PANEL cron job "command" section

```
   php -q http://example.com/users/test
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a cron job in cakephp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004216/run-a-cron-job-in-cakephp)

Comment: yes dublicate but not useful I alredy checked that

Comment: have you made a look on http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using controllers for cron jobs (via a url), cake has a console for doing just this.

Build a [shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell) and then add to your crontab

```
* * * * * </path/to/cake/>Console/cake -working </path/to/cake/> YourShell your_command --some-params -q
```

Adjust the `* * * * *` part to match what ever cycle you need

Adjust `</path/to/cake/>` as your absolute path to the cake app directory